# How to convert objects of JSON file into an array of objects , by using Jq?

Tags: json, linux, ubuntu, jq

I am just trying with this basic line, but I am not getting, here is the command.

```
echo {“x”:1} | jq '[ . ]'
```

It is showing the error as follows.

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9
```

The expected output is :

```
[{"x":1}]
```

Comment: `“` - is invalid quoting char

Comment: I have changed , even though it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`“` and `”` are invalid quoting chars, the valid quoting char is `"`.
The second moment is that the `echo` command arguments should be enclosed in single or double quotes (in conformity with argument content) to present a literal string:

```
echo '{"x":1}{"y":1}' | jq -s '.'
[
  {
    "x": 1
  },
  {
    "y": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: echo '{"x":1}{"y":1}' | jq  [.]    output is ::::   [
  {
    "x": 1
  }
]
[
  {
    "y": 1
  }
]
If I want output like [   {...}  {...}  ]  , what can I do?

Comment: @NagaVenkateshGavini, use `-s` option: `echo '{"x":1}{"y":1}' | jq -s '.'`